# Integrate Python based TensorFlow into a .NET application

Tags: c#, python, .net, tensorflow, keras

It seems that in order to fully use TensorFlow and associated libraries I need to access it from Python. Utilizing TensorFlow requires building rather complicated graphs which Python helper libraries (e.g. Keras) automate in sophisticated ways. I don't see a way to do that directly from .NET. See for example the [respective GitHub discussion about C# support](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/18#issuecomment-160804806).

My idea is this: The main C# application will call into a Python application to access TensorFlow. That way most code will remain in C# land. I can use CPython which has full support for everything (IronPython does not).

How would I go about "calling into a Python application"? I assume I will need to run `python.exe` in a child process and make it execute commands. The child process will need to remain running between commands so that I can keep/share objects and data.

How would I best go about doing this? I don't quite know where to start.

Comment: See this example: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/473

Comment: @denfromufa I'm aware of the .NET binding but that's just the raw TensorFlow API. The magic sits in additional libraries that make you good neural networks and other things. Everybody seems to write them in Python (e.g. Keras).

Comment: here is example for interacting with keras from pythonnet: https://github.com/LukaszSzulc/Pythonnetkeras

Comment: @denfromufa That looks really good! I will take a look.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/SciSharp/TensorFlow.NET which not only exposes the C API but also aims to port the complete Python layer.

Comment: I am working on a full Python API wrapper: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Gradient/ An example project built with it, using state of the art model (as of March 2019) https://github.com/losttech/BillionSongs

Answer (score 8):

Have a look on this:
https://github.com/migueldeicaza/TensorFlowSharp

TensorFlowSharp are .NET bindings to the TensorFlow library. This surfaces the C API as a strongly-typed .NET API for use from C# and F#.